# How do I get the Video Id from the URL? (Vimeo)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**PHP**

```
<?php

$url = 'http://vimeo.com/25451551';

/* http://www.vimeo.com/25451551 ... www.vimeo.com/25451551 */

$url = preg_match('???', $url);

echo $url;

?>
```

**Output**

```
25451551
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If video IDs are allowed to start with a 0, you may need to tune the following code a bit:

```
$url = 'http://vimeo.com/25451551';
sscanf(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/%d', $video_id);
// $video_id = int(25451551)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$url = 'http://vimeo.com/25451551/test';
$result = preg_match('/(\d+)/', $url, $matches);
if ($result) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```